# Get notification Title from BroadcastReceiver (direct reply Android N)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications

Since I'm building a messaging app, and there could be more than one notification with the direct reply, I need to be able to identify which one is sending the text in order to send the message to the right person... How could I achieve that ?

My thought was to get the title of the notification using extras, but I can't seem to get the extras in the BroadcastReceiver (in the Reply Reciever Activity). Extras only work when the notification is clicked and so dismissed (and so I can get the intent with the extra).

Here is the code of the notification :

```
resultIntent= new Intent(NotificationService.this, StartNAFromNS.class);
                        resultIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, underestood_name.replace("__", " "));


                        int Unique_Code = Retrieve_int("Unique_Code", 0, this);
                        Unique_Code=Unique_Code+1;
                        Save_int("Unique_Code", Unique_Code, this);


                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(NotificationService.this);
                        stackBuilder.addParentStack(SearchActivity.class);
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(Unique_Code,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        PendingIntent replyPendingIntent = null;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                            replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                    NotificationService.this,
                                    0,
                                    new Intent(NotificationService.this, ReplyReceiver.class),
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                            );
                        }
                        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_NOTIFICATION_REPLY)
                                .setLabel("Tapez votre réponse ici")
                                .build();
                        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action replyAction = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                                0, "Répondre", replyPendingIntent)
                                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                                .build();
                        miBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this)
                                .setGroup("Groupe01")
                                .setShowWhen(true)
                                .setSubText(summary)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_chat_bubble_outline_black_24dp)
                                .setContentTitle(mess_sender)
                                .setContentText(mess_contenu)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                            miBuilder.addAction(replyAction);
                        }
                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.notify(notif_id, miBuilder.build());
                        Log.wtf("Notification", "Displayed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive user input from the notification interface to the activity you declared in the reply action's intent:

1. Call getResultsFromIntent() by passing the notification action’s intent as the input parameter. This method returns a Bundle that contains the text response.

   ```
   Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
   ```
2. Query the bundle using the result key (provided to the `RemoteInput.Builder` constructor). You can complete this process and retrieve the input text by creating a method, as in the following code snippet:

   ```
   // Obtain the intent that started this activity by calling
   // Activity.getIntent() and pass it into this method to
   // get the associated string.

   private CharSequence getMessageText(Intent intent) {
       Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
       if (remoteInput != null) {
           return remoteInput.getCharSequence(KEY_NOTIFICATION_REPLY);
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
3. Build and issue another notification, using the same notification ID that you provided for the previous notification. The progress indicator disappears from the notification interface to inform users of a successful reply. When working with this new notification, use the context that gets passed to the receiver's `onReceive()` method.

   ```
   // Build a new notification, which informs the user that the system
   // handled their interaction with the previous notification.
   Notification repliedNotification =
           new Notification.Builder(context)
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
               .setContentText(getString(R.string.replied))
               .build();

   // Issue the new notification.
   NotificationManager notificationManager =
       NotificationManager.from(context);
   notificationManager.notify(notificationId, repliedNotification);
   ```

For details, please have a look:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html  **(Retrieving user input from the inline reply)**